# How to modify RecyclerView rows size when scrolling?

Tags: android, wear-os

anybody can tell me how it is possible to sync the row elements size with the row position : getting smaller when above or below center of screen to fit to round screen on android wear watch ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with wearables, you can use the `WearableListView`.

If so, in your adapter, you have your Item class which represents your row. This class can implement `WearableListView.OnCenterProximityListener`. There, you can animate your view in the callbacks : a small example without animation :

```
private static class Item extends LinearLayout implements WearableListView.OnCenterProximityListener {

    private FontTextView label;

    public Item(Context context) {
        super(context);
        View.inflate(context, R.layout.match_center_item, this);
        label = (FontTextView) findViewById(R.id.label);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCenterPosition(boolean animate) {
        label.setAlpha(EXPAND_LABEL_ALPHA);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNonCenterPosition(boolean animate) {
        label.setAlpha(SHRINK_LABEL_ALPHA);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add RecyclerView.OnScrollListener to your RecyclerView and in on Scrolled you can iterate over all of child and find they position on screen something like (kotlin code):

```
for(i in 0..this.childCount){
       val view   = this.getChildAt(i)
       when(i){
           in 0..this.childCount/2 -1->  {view.scaleX  = i.toFloat()/(this.childCount/2)
                                        view.scaleY== i.toFloat()/(this.childCount/2) }
           this.childCount/2 -> {view.scaleX = 1F ; view.scaleY = 1F}
           else ->{view.scaleX  = (this.childCount-i).toFloat()/(this.childCount/2)
                    view.scaleY== (this.childCount-i).toFloat()/(this.childCount/2) }
       }

   }
```